# how to dynamically send audio back in twilio stream after hearing the user input (send a specific answer according to user input)

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat

i'm tring to build a simple bot with twilio stream and google speech to text, that play a massage, pause hear the user input and return the answer that fit to the user input, but i can't find a way to send the answer back after getting the audio,
i mean that i dont know how to send "massages" from my server to twilio itself.

here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

let myAction = '<Say>default</Say>';

//Include Google Speech to Text
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

//Configure Transcription Request
const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: "MULAW",
        sampleRateHertz: 8000,
        languageCode: "iw-IL",
    },
    interimResults: true
    };

// Handle Web Socket Connection
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    console.log("New Connection Initiated");

    let recognizeStream = null;

    ws.on("message", function incoming(message) { 
        const msg = JSON.parse(message);
        switch (msg.event) {
            case "connected":
            console.log(`A new call has connected.`);

             // Create Stream to the Google Speech to Text API
            recognizeStream = client
            .streamingRecognize(request)
            .on("error", console.error)
            .on("data", data => {
            let answer = (data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
            if (answer?.includes('כן')){
                myAction="<Play>https://cinnamon-cockroach-2574.twil.io/assets/saidYes.mp3</Play>"
            }
            if(answer?.includes('לא')){
                myAction="<Play>https://cinnamon-cockroach-2574.twil.io/assets/saidNo.mp3</Play>"
            }
            });
            break;
            case "start":
            console.log(`Starting Media Stream ${msg.streamSid}`);
            break;
            case "media":
                // Write Media Packets to the recognize stream
                recognizeStream.write(msg.media.payload);
            break;
            case "stop":
            console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
            recognizeStream.destroy();
            break;
        }
    });
});

//Handle HTTP Request
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");

    res.send(`
    <Response>
        <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
        </Start>
        <Play>https://cinnamon-cockroach-2584.twil.io/assets/opening.mp3</Play>
        <Pause length="5" />
        ${myAction/* robot respond */}
        <Play>https://cinnamon-cockroach-2574.twil.io/assets/closing.mp3</Play>
    </Response>
    `);
});
console.log("Listening at Port 8080");
server.listen(8080);
```

***as*** you can see i tried to use ***myAction*** to dynamically set the answer for the user, but it doesnt work, i'll be glad to get some help or refernce to the right docs.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With `<Start><Stream .../></Start>` you're starting a stream asynchronously, see the [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream):

> The `<Start>` verb starts the audio `<Stream>` asynchronously and immediately continues with the next TwiML instruction. If there is no instruction, the call will be disconnected.

You probably want to have a synchronous bi-directional stream as described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect#stream) with `<Connect><Stream .../></Connect`.

Essentially what your TwiML would need to do is:

- Say opening message
- Connect the stream via `<Connect><Stream .../></Connect`, listen, do your processing with the Google Speech to Text API, store the result identified by telephone number in a database/cache and when done close the websocket
- Retrieve the result from the database/cache
- Say something in response to the result

The [Connect Basic Demo](https://github.com/twilio/media-streams/tree/master/node/connect-basic) should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: But how can i respond after my logic back to the user in the phone call?

Comment: The TwiML you return from your endpoint is the response. By returning it Twilio will ensure it gets delivered to the user.